# Find the function does describe the the percentage of the area that each circle overlaps

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, pi

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705384/find-the-percentage-of-the-area-of-each-circle-that-overlaps/3705428#3705428) question, yesterday and it got me thinking, what function does describe the the percentage of the area that each circle overlaps.

[image]

In that diagram it is given that the distance between the center of the circles is $1.5r$ but I want to generalize that to $nr$. The circles has the same radius.

Question: what function describes the problem I want to solve?

I tried using the answer that was given in the original problem, but that didn't bring me further. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://diego.assencio.com/?index=8d6ca3d82151bad815f78addf9b5c1c6

Comment: @hdighfan wow, impressive what a quick google search (I'm guessing) allows us to find!

Comment: @hdighfan Okay, but how can I find the other area of the two circles?

Comment: @Derik neat question, I am working on it because I think that the answer you mentioned in your question was my answer?!

Comment: @JanEerland Yes, that is right I was writing about your answer. Can you help me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's solve this by using some graphics. I define the following diagram:

[image]

The equation of a circle is given by:

$$\left(x-\text{a}\right)^2+\left(\text{y}-\text{b}\right)^2=\text{r}^2\tag1$$

Where $\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)$ are the center coordinates of the circle and $\text{r}$ is the radius of the circle.

We have two circles and they can be described using (which can be seen from the diagram above):

1. $$\left(x-\alpha_1\right)^2+\text{y}^2=\text{R}^2\tag2$$
2. $$\left(x-\alpha_2\right)^2+\text{y}^2=\text{R}^2\tag3$$

It is also not hard to see that $\alpha_1=\frac{\text{R}\Delta}{2}$ and $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1=-\frac{\text{R}\Delta}{2}$, using the diagram above.

Now, we can look at the following diagram:

[image]

If we combine both diagrams, we can see that $\epsilon_1=\left|\text{R}-\frac{\text{R}\Delta}{2}\right|=\text{R}\left|1-\frac{\Delta}{2}\right|$ and $\epsilon_2=-\epsilon_1=-\text{R}\left|1-\frac{\Delta}{2}\right|$. And using $(2)$ and/or $(3)$ we can solve for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$:

$$\left(0-\alpha_1\right)^2+\lambda_1^2=\text{R}^2\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\lambda_1=\sqrt{\left|\text{R}^2-\alpha_1^2\right|}\space\wedge\space\lambda_2=-\lambda_1=-\sqrt{\left|\text{R}^2-\alpha_1^2\right|}\tag4$$

Now, we take a look at the last diagram:

[image]

Using the first and the third diagram it is not hard to see that $\varphi_1=\text{R}+\frac{\text{R}\Delta}{2}=\text{R}\left(1+\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)$ and $\varphi_2=-\varphi_1=-\text{R}-\frac{\text{R}\Delta}{2}=-\text{R}\left(1+\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)$.

Now, we can solve $(2)$ and $(3)$ for the equation in the first quadrant in the first diagram:

- $$\left(x-\alpha_1\right)^2+\text{y}^2=\text{R}^2\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{y}=\sqrt{\text{R}^2-\left(x-\alpha_1\right)^2}\tag5$$
- $$\left(x-\alpha_2\right)^2+\text{y}^2=\text{R}^2\space\Longrightarrow\space\text{y}=\sqrt{\text{R}^2-\left(x-\alpha_2\right)^2}\tag6$$

Now, we can integrate to find the areas (using that a circle is symmetric):

- The total area in diagram 3 is given by:
  $$\mathcal{A}_1:=4\int_0^{\varphi_1}\sqrt{\text{R}^2-\left(x-\alpha_1\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=$$
  $$\frac{\text{R}^2}{2}\left(2\pi+\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}+4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)\right)\tag7$$
- The total area in diagram 2 is given by:
  $$\mathcal{A}_2:=4\int_0^{\epsilon_1}\sqrt{\text{R}^2-\left(x-\alpha_2\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=$$
  $$\frac{\text{R}^2}{2}\left(2\pi-\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}-4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)\right)\tag8$$

So, the desired fraction is given by:

$$\eta:=\frac{\mathcal{A}_2}{\mathcal{A}_1}=\frac{\frac{\text{R}^2}{2}\left(2\pi-\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}-4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{R}^2}{2}\left(2\pi+\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}+4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)\right)}=$$
$$\frac{2\pi-\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}-4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)}{2\pi+\Delta\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}+4\arctan\left(\frac{\Delta}{\sqrt{4-\Delta^2}}\right)}\tag9$$

> Note: these calculations only make sense when $0\le\Delta\le2$ and when $\Delta\to2$ we get (because we get a undetermined form):
>
> $$\lim_{\Delta\to2^-}\eta=0\tag{10}$$
>
> As the last step, we can plot $\eta$ as a function of $\Delta$:
>
> [image]

---

If you use Mathematica, you can use some code of me. In order to plot a complete diagram, you can use:

```
R =;
\[CapitalDelta] =;
\[Alpha]1 = (R*\[CapitalDelta])/2;
\[Alpha]2 = -\[Alpha]1;
\[Epsilon]1 = R*Abs[1 - (\[CapitalDelta]/2)];
\[Epsilon]2 = -\[Epsilon]1;
\[Lambda]1 = Sqrt[Abs[R^2 - \[Alpha]1^2]];
\[Lambda]2 = -\[Lambda]1;
\[Phi]1 = R*(1 + (\[CapitalDelta]/2));
\[Phi]2 = -\[Phi]1;
ContourPlot[{(x - \[Alpha]1)^2 + y^2 == 
   R^2, (x - \[Alpha]2)^2 + y^2 == R^2}, {x, -2 R, 2 R}, {y, -2 R, 
  2 R}, GridLines -> {{0, \[Alpha]1, \[Alpha]2, \[Epsilon]1, \
\[Epsilon]2, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}, {0, \[Lambda]1, \[Lambda]2}}]
```

In order to evaluate the integral $(7)$, you can use:

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  4 Sqrt[R^2 - (x - ((R*\[CapitalDelta])/2))^2], {x, 0, 
   R*(1 + (\[CapitalDelta]/2))}, Assumptions -> R > 0 && \[CapitalDelta] > 0]]
```

In order to evaluate the integral $(8)$, you can use:

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  4 Sqrt[R^2 - (x - (-(R*\[CapitalDelta])/2))^2], {x, 0, 
   R*Abs[1 - (\[CapitalDelta]/2)]}, Assumptions -> R > 0 && \[CapitalDelta] > 0]]
```

And so $\eta$ is found by:

```
FullSimplify[(1/
    2 R^2 (2 \[Pi] - \[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2] - 
      4 ArcTan[\[CapitalDelta]/Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2]]))/(1/
    2 R^2 (2 \[Pi] + \[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2] + 
      4 ArcTan[\[CapitalDelta]/Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2]])), 
 Assumptions -> R > 0 && \[CapitalDelta] > 0]
```

And the plot of $\eta$ as a function of $\Delta$ is made using:

```
Plot[(2 \[Pi] - \[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2] - 
  4 ArcTan[\[CapitalDelta]/Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2]])/(
 2 \[Pi] + \[CapitalDelta] Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2] + 
  4 ArcTan[\[CapitalDelta]/Sqrt[4 - \[CapitalDelta]^2]]), {\[CapitalDelta], 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[\[CapitalDelta]], HoldForm[\[Eta]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

Comment: Wow, let me study this. Thank you soo much.